# Spring Security authentication no longer working

Tags: spring, spring-security

For the past few days Ive been able to authenticate but recently after have to reinstall my program I can no longer authenticate. There is no error message, the hql query shows in the console and the page redirects back to the login page.

The security xml

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

<intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" />
<intercept-url pattern='/admin/admin/**' access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<intercept-url pattern='/main/home/**' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
<intercept-url pattern='/main/user/setter/settingpage' 

access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
<intercept-url pattern='/main/user/setter/addpage' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

<form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/main/home" />
<logout logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" />
```

Output query

```
    Hibernate: select userentity0_.user_id as user1_2_, userentity0_.active as 

    active2_, userentity0_.checker_id as checker7_2_, userentity0_.email as email2_, 

    userentity0_.name as name2_, userentity0_.password as password2_, 

    userentity0_.username as username2_ from user userentity0_ where 

    userentity0_.username=?
```

I would appreciate knowing why I can't logon anymore.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems in your configuration:

1) You do not configure the login URL (it can not be `\`)

```
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/main/home" />
```

2) Do not add authorization on login URLs. Add this line in the beginning (before `pattern='/main/home/**'`)

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
```